# How to isolate specific words and years in group 1 no matter the combination

Tags: regex

I got some values coming in with various look such as

- autumn ux-s 2021
- 2021 pes-3 autumn P-S
- pes-3 autumn 2021 32
- autumn usd- fosd 2021 2

I really want to isolate "autumn" and "2021" - both in group 1

Of course the "autumn" could also be "spring", "summer", "winter" while the year of course should match the year.

It doesnt matter if i get "2021 autumn" and "autumn 2021" as long as i can isolate it within the same group 1

How could i achieve this? I simply cant see how i can keep it within one single group ?

I can isolate the location here, but of course still match the whole thing

```
((?:(?:autumn|spring)(?:\s*[a-zA-Z]*\s*)\d{4})|(?:\d{4}(?:\s*[a-zA-Z]*\s*)(?:autumn|spring)))
```

Can i somehow substract only partials from here and combine them into a single group result?

Comment: Why do you want to season and year be in 1 group?

Comment: And what's your programming language or your flavor regex?

Comment: My current code requires my result to always be in group 1!

Run it in Python and always in insensitive mode

Answer (score -1):

I did not find a regex to capture what you want in 1 group but maybe this one-liner solution helps you?

```
import re

text = ["autumn ux-s 2021", "2021 pes-3 autumn P-S", "pes-3 autumn 2021 32" ,"autumn usd- fosd 2021 2"]
pattern = r"(autumn|summer|winter|spring).*(\d{4})|(\d{4}).*(autumn|summer|winter|spring)"

print([' '.join(filter(None, re.search(pattern, txt, re.IGNORECASE).groups())) for txt in text])
```

output: `['autumn 2021', '2021 autumn', 'autumn 2021', 'autumn 2021']`

Comment: Thanks, was hoping to avoid code changes though as it also handles hundreds of other cases